# Why LSTM provides different prediction with different batch_size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to experiment with a stateless LSTM model on a large dataset and trying to understand the effect of batch_size on the prediction.
What I understand is that in model.predict, the batch_size will just dictate how many outputs that the model should make at the same time and it should not affect the model configuration or anything.

However, I noticed that upon using different batch_size in prediction, the results are slightly different.

I have included a sample code to illustrate. Output of batch_size = 1, preds_1, is different from that of batch_size = 10, preds_10.

What could have caused the differences?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# Generate sample data
data = np.random.rand(200, 10, 30)
target = np.random.rand(200, 1)

# Create a simple stateless LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(10, 30)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Fit the model on the sample data
model.fit(data, target, epochs=5, batch_size=32)

# Generate new test data
test_data = np.random.rand(20, 10, 30)

# Make predictions with batch size 1
batch_size_1 = 1
model.reset_states()
preds_1 = model.predict(test_data, batch_size=batch_size_1)

# Make predictions with batch size 10
batch_size_10 = 10
model.reset_states()
preds_10 = model.predict(test_data, batch_size=batch_size_10)
```

```
preds_1==preds_10

array([[False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [False]])
```

Comment: Comparing floats with a simple equality is not ideal. For instance, `tf.debugging.assert_near(preds_1, preds_10)` returns true.

Comment: Is the calculation deterministic? Do you get the same answer if you repeat the calculation with the same batch size?

Comment: Thanks, Plagon and myrtlecat. @myrtlecat, when I use the same model (no re-fitting), it would show the same result.

Comment: I re-run your code and printed the predictions and found out that they are super close (0.5769916, 0.5769915). But when using the same batch on different predict calls I always get the same values. So I am assuming there might be an implicit normalization inside the LSTM cells that uses batches statistics.